# Can you get the network password when someone tries to connect?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, passwords, man-in-the-middle

could you get the network password of a network if a device tries to connect to the network by name with the password, but the network is basically a MITM Network?

I don't know how to formulate this into a sentence, basically, if a network, let's say Network-One has a password and a device that connects to this network, finding it by name, could I create a network of the same name (Network-One) and wait for the device to try and connect to my "fake" network, then sniff the connection packet and get the password?

If even just a hash of the password, could I get the password that way?

> Router/Network: WPA/WPA2

This will probably be done in Linux (Kali or ParrotOS), but how, is there a tutorial or something?

[explanation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GarWO.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What makes you think the password is transmitted in cleartext? That would be childsplay to hack. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/174221/how-does-a-device-send-the-wi-fi-password-to-the-router and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/110927/how-does-wpa2-psk-prevent-evil-twin-password-phishing